# Keep an Application Running even if an unhandled Exception occurs

Tags: c#, .net

**What ?**
I am developing a Console Application that needs to keep running 24/7 **No Matter What**
Is there any way to stop a Multi-Threaded Application from getting blown up by some unhandled exception happening in "some thread somewhere" ?

**Why ?**
Please refrain from giving lessons like "you should manage all your exceptions", "this should never happen" etc. I have my reasons : We are in test deployment and we need to keep this running, log exceptions, and restart all threads again. If **anything unplanned** happens and causes an unhandled exception to be thrown, it needs to be detected and some method called to restart all threads(atomicity is impossible due due the tier design)

This being said, I am aware it might no be possible to restart an application from "within" if it has blown because of and UnhandledException (which I already implemented).

So far, I have used Quartz.net's FileScan Job and a Flag File to detect stuff like that and restart the application from outwards. But this sounds hacky to me. I would like to find something cleaner and less quick and dirty.

*DownVoting / Sniping Warning : I KNOW this might NOT be possible "as is'". 
Please be creative/helpful rather than abruptly critic and think of this more as an "Open question"*

Comment: So...you add a "downvote" warning for your "open question" and then downvote everyone who tries to help you. Nice...

Comment: @EthanCabiac Sorry for that, your answer was "not really" an answer for the reason I commented first. After your edit that was different. I will mark it as an answer as this is the choice I have posted myself as an answer to myself. Let's make-peace :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler to UnhandledException event on the Current AppDomain:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler`

Inside the handler, you will have to somehow save enough state (to a file, database, etc.) for the restarted application to pass along to the new threads. Then instantiate a new instance of your Console application with a call to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyConsoleApp.exe")`.

Be very careful to introduce logic to avoid a continuous loop of crash/restart/crash/restart.

Comment: This is already implemented. In no way this will help anything get restarted. App will exit after the handler does its job

Comment: @Mika: If the way you implemented the exception handler doesn't restart your program, that's not the exception handler's fault, that's just behavior you haven't implemented in your UnhandledExceptionHandler.

Comment: @RobertP : Well this is a VERY important point : the exception handler does what it is told to, yes, BUT, correct me if I am wrong, the Application IS terminated just after the handler exits. Which makes my point : It does not allow the App to stay alive.

Comment: +1/Marked as an answer : The edit was posted at the same time I wrote my answer with the full code (see below) which basically reproduces the same idea I came up with finally.

Comment: Your last remark is very sensible. This is a caveat I have identified and alluded to among the drawbacks in my answer. It should be tackled carefully indeed.

Comment: Just to mention, for future readers, that JohnFx's Windows Service suggestion is more elegant and should be preferred. I am chosing the UnhandledException handler because it is more straightforward for a quick fix, although I will probably implement a service later.

Comment: Just an FYI: catching errors via the UnhandledExceptionHandler will NOT catch, for example, an abort() call in a C++ DLL that you're P/Invoking.

Answer (score 12):

If it is going to run 24/7 anyway, why not just [write it as a Windows service](http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/) and take advantage of the recovery options built right into windows?

[image: Configuring Recovery Services]

This approach has the additional advantage of being able to survive a machine reboot, and it will log failures/restarts in the system event logs.

Comment: I would really want to avoid the use of a service and keep everything non-OS-Bound

Comment: What OS do you need to support? Seems odd that you'd do non-windows programming in C#.

Comment: @Mika: Then separate the non-os specific parts from the OS specific parts.  You're allowed to write multiple objects or libraries. :)

Comment: @JohnFx I did not make myself clear : It will run under windows but I would rather keep anything under control in my own application rather than introducing an external-handling to it. This was my question at first. I really would like to know if suck thing is possible

Comment: It wouldn't be external handling. Make your program a service. It already sounds like one if you are running it 24/7.

Comment: @Mika: Perhaps you don't understand the point of a service.  It's code that *you* write to do a particular job that needs to happen all the time.  Of course it's possible to do yourself; C# is Turing complete, so anything you need is possible.  With a service, you just happen to leave the 'restart when things fail' part to the OS.  Microsoft wrote code to do that job for you.  It's ok to use it.  In fact, it's better if you use the OS to do it, because Microsoft has paid highly skilled people to work on this exact problem for decades.  They solved it for you.  Take advantage of it. :)

Comment: @MikaJacobi: the support of Windows Services is part of Windows. You can control how the knobs are set, but if it's good enough for all existing Windows Services, then the chances are it's good enough for you.

Comment: @RobertP, John Saunders and JohnFx : Ok Then you are right. Looks like I have to re-write some stuff based in this. Thank you for your support

Comment: I'll be implementing the Service soon for the next version delivery. I'll go for a process restart in an UnhandledException handler as a quick fix for now.

Answer (score 4):

- You **can't** keep a process running "no matter what". What if the process is killed?
- You **don't want to** keep a process running "no matter what". What if the process state is corrupted in such a way that "bad things" happen if it keeps running?

Comment: I stated "Please refrain from giving lessons" :-) I am getting used to such non-answers on SOF but they always itch me. Don't be so darn literal ! by "No matter Matter What" I mean "No matter Matter What Happens wrong in the program" ! 
PLUS, if the process state is corrupted, I will be notified by mail and see it on the server. Plus I have my bad state management logic. But I need it to keep stuff running and  restarded in the night if there's a hitch.

Comment: @mika: You asked for help about something you obviously don't understand. If you don't want a "lesson" then don't ask for help.

Comment: For some reason this whole post feels like the start of a Raymond Chen blog post.

Comment: @EthanCabiac : You obviously mistake "out of the box thinking" for "lack of understanding". Plus I said : "I am aware it might no be possible" I am just VERY curious and I never take a plain No for an answer. There are always possibilities to push things further than "general habitus"

Comment: @MikaJacobi: I heard you and ignored you. SO isn't just about answering the question for you - it's also about answering the question for everyone else who reads it.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is in line with my statements. The Windows Service solution doesn't keep a process running _no matter what_, it automatically restarts the process if it fails.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sir, I know you, your assertions are often right, and you have already often answered in a very sensible way to some of my questions, and I respect that. However, this time, no offense, I may disagree because what you said is totally right but it is not useful as an answer to my issue. (Well not directly). If you just want to share knowledge you could use a blog :-) Anyway, I totally get your point on how you see SO, and partially agree. Peace to you :)

Comment: @MikaJacobi: Yes, if I had more time, I would have responded with my two bullet points and then said, "_therefore_, you should use a Windows Service".

Answer (score 2):

Well I can think of a few drawbacks in the following solution, but it is good enough to me for the moment :

```
static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
        CS = new ConsoleServer();
        CS.Run();            
    }

    public static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
        Logger.Log("UNHANDLED EXCEPTION : " + e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Process.Start(@"C:\xxxx\bin\x86\Release\MySelf.exe");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your using .Net 2.0 and above, the answer is you can't.

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, an unhandled exception
>   that occurs in a thread other than the main application thread is
>   caught by the runtime and therefore does not cause the application to
>   terminate. Thus, it is possible for the UnhandledException event to be
>   raised without the application terminating. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0, this backstop for unhandled exceptions in child
>   threads was removed, because the cumulative effect of such silent
>   failures included performance degradation, corrupted data, and
>   lockups, all of which were difficult to debug. For more information,
>   including a list of cases in which the runtime does not terminate, see
>   Exceptions in Managed Threads.

Taken from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

If you want your application to survive, then you will need very aggressive try/catch around your methods so nothing escapes.

I would advise using a windows service as mentioned by others.  It's the same as a console application, but with an extra bit of service layer code on top.  You could take your console app and covert it to a service application easily.  Just need to override service.start/pause/stop methods.

Comment: Thank you for your sensible instruction. Very Instructive Indeed.